# How to crop image after upload Cloudinary?

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

How i can to crop image after upload and send edited response ulr to frontent?
I will be grateful for the answer

MY CODE:

```
const stream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(
  {
    folder,
  },
  (error: UploadApiErrorResponse | undefined, result: UploadApiResponse | undefined): void => {
    console.log(error, result)
    if (result) {
      resolve({
        url: result.url,
        size: Math.round(result.bytes / 1024),
        height: result.height,
        width: result.width,
      })
    } else {
      reject(error)
    }
  }
)

streamifier.createReadStream(buffer).pipe(stream)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common method of integrating Cloudinary is that you upload the original file to your Cloudinary account and store the Upload API response to your database which contains the details for the image: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#sample_response

If you don't want to store the entire response, you should store at least the fields needed to create a URL for that image later: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#transformation_url_structure

(Which are `public_id`, `resource_type`, `type`, `format`, and `timestamp`) though strictly speaking, most of those are optional if your assets are images of type 'upload' - certainly you need the public_id though.

Then, in your frontend code, when adding the image to your page or to your application, you add transformation parameters when building the URL, asking that the image is returned with transformations applied to match it to where/how you're using the image.

A common option is to set the width and height to exactly match the image tag or image view, then apply automatic cropping if the aspect ratio of the original doesn't match, with the crop selection being automatic: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/resizing_and_cropping

A Javascript example to add those parameters, if the image should be 500x500 is:

```
cloudinary.url( public_id,
  {
   resource_type: 'image', //these are the defaults and can be ommitted
   type: 'upload', //these are the defaults and can be ommitted
   height: 500,
   width: 500,
   crop: 'lfill', // try to fill the requested width and height without scaling up, crop if needed
   gravity: 'auto', // select which area to keep automatically
   fetch_format: 'auto',
   quality: 'auto',
   format: 'jpg',  // sets the file extension on the URL, and will convert to that format if needed, and no fetch_format was set to override that
  });
```

The resulting URL will be something like: http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/c_lfill,f_auto,g_auto,h_500,q_auto,w_500/sample.jpg